# Creating new Rc instances without taking ownership

Tags: rust, reference, smart-pointers, borrow-checker

Say I have the following code:

```rs
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Struct {}

struct Pair {
    first: Rc<Struct>,
    second: Rc<Struct>
}

fn pair_lists(vec:Vec<Struct>) -> Vec<Pair> {
    let mut pair = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..vec.len() {
        for j in i+1..vec.len() {
            let new_pair = Pair {
                first: Rc::new(vec[i]),
                second: Rc::new(vec[j])
            };
            pair.push(new_pair);
        }
    }
    pair
}

fn main() {
}
```

This will not compile because in the function `pair_lists`, `Rc::new` will take ownership of the `vec`:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Struct>`
  --> src/main.rs:15:32
   |
15 |                 first: Rc::new(vec[i]),
   |                                ^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Struct`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Struct>`
  --> src/main.rs:16:33
   |
16 |                 second: Rc::new(vec[j])
   |                                 ^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Struct`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

However, I don't want to create an overhead by copying all the instances of `vec`; ideally, there should only be one copy of each element in memory.

What is the rust idiomatic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert `vec` into a `Vec<Rc<Struct>>` first, and then clone the `Rc`s from that:

```
fn pair_lists(vec:Vec<Struct>) -> Vec<Pair> {
    let vec: Vec<Rc<Struct>> = vec
        .into_iter()
        .map(Rc::new)
        .collect();

    let mut pair = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..vec.len() {
        for j in i+1..vec.len() {
            let new_pair = Pair {
                first: Rc::clone(&vec[i]),
                second: Rc::clone(&vec[j]),
            };
            pair.push(new_pair);
        }
    }
    pair
}
```

Creating the pairs from the vec can also be accomplished by using `.tuple_windows()` from the `itertools` crate:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

fn pair_lists(vec:Vec<Struct>) -> Vec<Pair> {
    vec.into_iter()
        .map(Rc::new)
        .tuple_windows()
        .map(|(first, second)| Pair { first, second, })
        .collect()
}
```